# preg_replace impossible to delete the space inside string

Tags: php

> My string is "1 049"

Impossible to delete to space and get 1049, what i'm doing wrong ?

```
$distance // "1 049"
$distance = $str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $distance);

$distance // "1 049"
```

UPDATE

i get a json result from google distance api, the two str_replace works but i try to make a preg_replace at the end in order to get 1049 instead of "1 049"

```
   $response = \GoogleMaps::load('directions')
        ->setParam([
            'origin'          => $origin,
            'destination'     => $destination,
            'mode' => 'driving' ,
            'language' => 'fr',

        ])->get();

    $parsed_json = (json_decode($response));

    if($parsed_json->status != "NOT_FOUND") {
        $result = $parsed_json->{'routes'}[0]->{'legs'}[0]->{'distance'}->{'text'};
        $a = $result;
        $b = str_replace(" km",'',$a);
        $distance = str_replace(",",'.',$b);
        $distance = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $distance);
    }

var_dump($distance) // "1 049"
```

Comment: Any reason you want to use a regex instead of `str_replace(' ', '', $distance)`?

Comment: Can you add what the content of `$result` is so we know what string you are working with? e.g. `var_dump($result)`

Comment: we get "1 049 km" @ArSeN

Comment: I edited my answer to solve your updated question

Comment: i finally found a solution, get now the value parameter in meters and not a string.  many thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You are matching for "one space" `\s` followed by "one or more spaces" `\s+` which means at least two spaces together.
2. Your replace text is still a space and not an empty string.

You are looking for this:

```
var_dump(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', '1 049'));
```

However this can also be done simpler with str_replace():

```
var_dump(str_replace(' ', '', '1 049'));
```

**EDIT**

Based on your update to the original question and the fact that you thankfully copy&pasted the value to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60356058/preg-replace-impossible-to-delete-the-space-inside-string?noredirect=1#comment106776019_60356058) I could find out that what you are trying to get rid off is not actually white space, but of a different character which `ord()` number is `226`. All code pages I could find say it is an `â` or an `ô` but weirdly enough those are just shown, whereas your character is not. Maybe someone else can explain which character it actually is.

See [3v4l.org snippet](https://3v4l.org/PUHD1) (I could not get stackoverflow to show the character):

[image]

That being said, you have two options:

1) You could just replace that special character and get rid of it:

```
// note that SO shows it as whitespace but your mystery character is in there!
var_dump(str_replace(' ', '', '1 049'));
```

2) Or, the probably better approach, since you basically only want numbers you can save the previous steps and instead of

```
$a = $result;
$b = str_replace(" km",'',$a);
$distance = str_replace(",",'.',$b);
$distance = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $distance);
```

you could just repleace everything that is not numbers away in one step:

```
$distance = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $result);
```

Comment: just a json result

Comment: i didn't mention that :/

Comment: JSON? What? We are talking about strings here! If your question is something totally different then please add so in the question. You tagged it with PHP.

Comment: i casted the json to a string by the way

Comment: Please edit this question rather than making a new one

Answer (score -1):

Say your string is:

```
cash = '1 049'
```

all you have to do is

```
cash.replace(' ', '')
```

Which will remove any white spaces.
I hope this helped

Comment: This is not a PHP answer but possibily for a different programming language.